# Why animals have to breathe?

Tags: creature-design, natural-resources, worldbuilding-resources

First time poster, let me know if this is not about world building.

I am not asking about the function of respiration nor the chemical effect of oxygen and stuff. I am asking if there is any good reasons to force my creatures "to repeatedly perform an action for their whole lives in order to maintain their lives, while such action does not require any extra input and is essentially free and involuntary".

While these continuous life supporting actions include also eating, drinking, resting and excreting, all these require extra work or effort (e.g. hunting, sheltering, cleaning), only breathing is basically free. Air is provided, no harvesting is needed. Supply is virtually infinite, no over consumption issue, hence no war, no fighting because of resource depletion.

So why would I create creatures in my world requiring them to perform this seemingly unnecessary action to consume an infinite resource provided for free?

It seems to me this is just a mean to separate the territories of my creatures, e.g. terrestrial vs aquatic creatures. While the resource is infinite, the tools capable to consume the resource can be different, some specialised for one, some both. Another reason I could think of is to limit the movement boundaries of my creatures by setting up a space that does not have this resource, so that my creatures would hold captive their entire lives within an enclosed place.

Those are just my thoughts though. But then again, as civilisation advances, my creatures would overcome this limitation and start colonising in other territories or even planets, so it seems this is only there to delay this process? I hope there can be some important reasons behind to justify doing this that I overlooked?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. Are you looking for an answer to a concrete problem or just for some philosophical discussion? Because here we do the first, and I don't see trace of a concrete problem in your question. Also, I would challenge that breathing costs no effort or that it is free and available everywhere. Last time I dove to catch some fish I had to come to surface from time to time...

Comment: "Air is provided, no harvesting is needed " : why do YOU breathe then ?

Comment: Thanks. I am asking what good reason there is for me to create a world by forcing my creatures to breathe. As for your challenge there, I have said that can be a mean to separate the territories of my creatures.

Comment: @GlorfSf this is not about the world I am in, so why I breathe or not has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: but it does : you breathe because it is a necessary effort to gather oxygen. The real question is : "why wouldn't my animals breath ?, where would they gather the energy provided by oxygen (or anything else) ?"

Comment: @GlorfSf you have to think outside the box. Think about a world that does not require oxygen, or oxygen can be generated within any creatures cells. In fact you are just repeating my question: why I would want to create my creatures to breathe in order to gather an essential life supporting resource?

Comment: Breathing is free (needs not too much energy/brain resource/extra time) once you have your organs for it. But breathing organs are not free: They occupy large internal volume which coud be used for other purpose, and are to be protected, since they are vulnearble to sudden changes in pressure, to inhaling of liquids or smoke, to TBC and pneumonia... And yes, there is a competition in the evolutionary sense over beathing organs. Although air is unlimited, the actual amount a being can consume in unit time is limited by it's lungs. Birds benefit heavily from their advanced lungs while flying.

Comment: I don't get the question. Are you asking why your animals should have to breathe? Well, if you don't see a reason, don't have them breathe. There is no rule that says: Do whatever you wish in fiction, go faster than light, travel through a black hole, have a dog play soccer, just don't have animals that don't breathe.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Surely I understand that. But as we already have an example here and its common in fictions to dictate how air plays an important role (e.g. when visiting an unknown planet), I just don't want to skip some possible important reasons why breathing is required for creatures by just saying here is a world full of creatures that do not breathe. In other words, what possible consequences I may have in my world if my creatures do not breathe? e.g early extinction of weaker creatures due to early invasion?

Comment: Are you asking how to design an animal that doesn't have to breathe? If so, state so

Comment: @Raditz_35 No. I am asking for any good reasons to justify why I would want to force my creatures to perform a life supporting action continuously that does not require extra effort with an infinite resource provided for free. A less comparable analogue would be "Desmond in Lost has to push a button every 108 mins in order to survive", my reason would be to keep Desmond's movement within certain area. If the button is automatic, consequence is Desmond can go anywhere he wants.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you willing to create a god designed planet, where each creature has a specific place assigned? Or are you looking for alternatives to breathing, like using a liquid oxidizing agent? If you're wondering why animals happen to breathe, Renan answered you.

Comment: @user1589188 The best and easiest answer to this question i thy have to breathe in order to get sufficient oxygen to survive. I don't see why this couldn't answer your question.

Comment: I'm not gonna give up so easily and keep guessing what the question is. Do you want to know what you can do in your world to make use of the fact that they cannot go places they cannot breathe? Do you want to know about more places certain animals can't breathe than the ones you've already mentioned? Do you want to know how to make the fact that they breathe an interesting subject because it seems rather irrelevant to you to mention it since it's free or something? Do you want to know about evolutionary pressures to develop breathing even though there is no competition (getting esoteric here)?

Comment: Cheers everyone.Lets not dwell on breathing.There is a bunch of robots,they need charging to function.There are power outlets everywhere on my planet,but different plugs.Energy is free and infinite.Outside my planet there is no power outlets.Effectivly I have limited the territories of the robots.One day a robot asks me,why I didn't create them solar powered so that they do not need to recharge from outlets regularly.What would be the reason for me to justify why I didnt want to do that?Is territory separation to robots of different plugs the only reason?

Comment: This is a question I understand. "Why would someone design robots that can only be recharged in a small area?" Why don't you edit your original question so this thread might be reopened?

Comment: @Raditz_35 Glad that now you understand.But the question is still about breathing.The robot example is just to help you understand.While charging is all the robot needs.Breathing is not.You also need eating and drinking.But both are not free,only breathing is.So the question is still why breathing?

Comment: So your question is: "What reason does an all-powerful/all-knowing (something like that) creator have to create animals that breathe if one postulates that the creator could've come up with a way so that animals work just like they do now with the only difference that they do not need to breathe?"

Comment: @Raditz_35 In a specific way of speaking,yes.But not guessing the intention of an all-knowing creator.Only you,your reason,if you are to answer that.And not breathing in particular,generally an action that is life supporting and has to do regularly without effort.The robots example again,you as a creator forces them to tweet you at specific hours or else they explode.And network is free and no cost.

Comment: Then this is sadly off-topic here, see the first comment: "Are you looking for an answer to a concrete problem or just for some philosophical discussion? Because here we do the first". I believe the question as I have asked it would be on-topic, but I of course might be biased

Comment: If the possibility of not needing to breathe is available, then certainly there is no good reason to create a creature that does need it. A need is by definition a weakness, so if you **can** make a creature without needs, then there is no good reason to make it with them.
But, as interesting as this question is, I believe it is really off-topic.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Now is my turn failing to understand how this is off-topic.All questions are asking others' best knowledge,not definite answer.@Ray the "need" is not for the creatures,I believe the "need" is more for the creator."What benefits a creator possibly have by forcing his creatures to perform some life supporting action regularly and provide them infinite resource to do that effortlessly?".

Comment: @user1589188 In that case, there is not enough information. Who would this creator be? What are their motivations? Why did they create creatures in the first place? To know what benefits would a creator get we need to know what benefits the creator seeks to achieve by creating the creature in the first place.

Comment: Do you want to hear other people's opinions or do you just say that nobody knows most things for sure and no answer is perfect? E.g. "What would you do?" is off-topic, this is a Q&A and not a forum, "What can be done?" not necessarily

Comment: @Raditz_35 I am not following.What is your on-topic version of the question you said?Happy to just change my question into your on-topic way of asking.Cheers.

Comment: I cannot guarantee anything. I cannot even cast votes. But as you can see your current question has been closed

Answer (score 4):

There are many creatures in our world that do not have to move their gills/branchea/trachea/lungs in order to breath. Earthworms, flatworms, sponges and microbes, for example. They just let the oxygen diffuse into their bodies.

Notice that while the oxygen supply in our atmosphere is (for practical purposes only and from the point of view of an animal) practically infinite, the speed at which you absorb it is not. There is just so much you can take in at a time. This flux limitation is also a threshold for how intense your activities may be. Many animals have evolved specializations that help them take in larger amounts of oxygen, and this is usually associated with animals that rely on intense bursts of speed or endurance in one way or another.

For example, sharks and tuna increase their amount of oxygen intake (related to similar sized fish) by ram-breathing. If they stay in one spot without moving they may suffocate.

Flying birds have their chest muscles attached to their sternum. This means that when flying, each flap of the wings causes a full intake/outtake cycle of air to happen. This is how humming birds are capable of flapping their wings so fast, and it also helps other species during long flights, or when they need to either hunt or escape from a predator.

In your world where creatures just let oxygen diffuse through their bodies, whatever species develops a way to increase the flow of air through them will become much "faster", possibly stronger (more oxygen for the muscles) than their competitors, and may have an evolutionary edge depending on the environment where they live.

Comment: Insects do that, but without an air pump it's very limited and one of the reasons insects are so small

Comment: Thanks. So you are suggesting even though the resource is free, the rate of consuming this life supporting resource can be a mean to control the evolution rate of different creatures?

Comment: @user1589188 no, I had not thought about controlling evolution. My point is that for two creatures of similar shape, mass, habits etc. A creature that is able to use harness more energy (for hunting/escaping, for example) will have tremendous advantage over their slower, weaker counterpart. On a very high level that is why animals that cannot rely on speed have to rely on hard shells/thick hides or camouflage to survive. At the same time a usual top predator feature in any ecossystem is being strong and fast, which implies large lungs or ram-breathing.

Comment: @user1589188 we could make an analogy with computers. Electricity from a wall outlet is practically unlimited for the purposes of feeding a computer. If you use a machine just to play solitaire and minefield, you don't need an expensive NVidia/Radeon chipset, and therefore you don't need a powerful UPS. But if you are going to play the latest FPS games you are going to need a graphic chipset that will probably require a 600+ Watts UPS in order to work. The UPS is then, to the computer, what a lung is to an animal.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the difference here. But then why would I want to have creatures to consume this energy only under the sea or above the ground?

Comment: @user1589188 nature does not have wants. Nature does not even have needs. Gills and branchea evolved underwater, and lungs and trachea above water, because each confered to their owners significant advantages.

Comment: Hummm,you are trying to explain the conceived world of nature.But in fact I am asking from a creator's point of view,why I would want to create creatures that breathe.And incidentally or not,I created creatures that can only breathe under the sea or above the ground.And no air outside my planet.And I am asking the good reasons why I would want to do that.

Comment: @user1589188 do you mean "god" instead of "good"? If so, that will vary from god to god. Your fictional deity could justify it because their creatures are one with the world, and *"they eat the earth and drink the air"*. Were I writing it, I would make creatures breath for the same reason that I would have the first species to tame fire being one that lives in the woods - because my book story would begin with "I am the Creator - and this is jackass!"